# How to view certificates from my keychain on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, keychain, ssl

On macOS the keychain allows me to view all certificates and if I want manually revoke trust to a certificate. I was wondering how I could do something similar on my iPhone as my school forces me to install their intermediate certificate to use their Wi-Fi, which I would like to revoke when not at school to prevent the school from man in the middle attacking/creating fake SSL certificates for websites I view outside of school.

Comment: I've expanded the title of the question to be specific about certificates, since passwords are shown elsewhere in Settings and don't appear to be what you're looking for in this question, but feel free to [edit] further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find certificates installed on your device in Settings → General → About → Certificate Trust Settings. Here you can switch root certificates on and off as you please.

[image]

As shown by the small words in the screenshot, certificates enforced by a profile can't be modified here. Profiles are installed in Settings → General → Profiles. You can't turn such certificates on/off — instead you have to uninstall and reinstall the profile.

Comment: doesnt let me revoke trust to root certificates built into the device but ill still mark this answer as correct as i doubt ios lets you do what i want